# Vue.js lint forces component to a single line

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, eslint, prettier

I have a component in Vue template

```
 <MyComponent
  class='class'
  someattribute='...'
  @event='eventListener'
/>
```

When I try to run lint it automatically reformats my code to following

```
 <MyComponent class='class' someattribute='...' @event='eventListener' />
```

I'm trying to disable it from doing so but can't find any corresponding rule. Any ideas how to avoid this?

I just want it to stay however I write it and disable any rules regarding it.

Comment: I have the same question, look like there is no rule to force single line when there is less then some number of attributes. It works only with one attribute using 'vue/first-attribute-linebreak': ['error', { singleline: 'beside' }],

Answer (score 1):

you should not do this, single line props are recommended by Vue officially:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Multi-attribute-elements-strongly-recommended

If you really want to change it.

- in your `package.json` file, find if there is a `eslintConfig`

  - if it has, add this config in its `rules`: `"vue/max-attributes-per-line": "off"`
- if no `eslintConfig`, you can add one. the default config should look like this:

```
"eslintConfig": {
//... other config
       "rules": {
      "vue/max-attributes-per-line": "off"
    }
  },
```